# Warning Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Missing '='

Tags: if, contains

I don't know what is wrong in the formula bellow:

[image]

Comment: Please share your code as text, not an image. Images are not accessible to users who utilize screen readers or other assistive technology. You can make an [edit] to your post.

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to use the [ and ] in this context. Just delete those and the formula will be correct.